# Make variable final

Tags: java, final

```
@Component
public class PathConstant {

    @Value("#{systemProperties['system.uploadDir']}")
    public String tempPath;

    public static String FILE_UPLOAD_PATH; // <------------------

    @PostConstruct
    public void initConstant() {
        FILE_UPLOAD_PATH = tempPath;
    }
}
```

I'd like to make FILE_UPLOAD_PATH final so that no one can modify its value.

I believe it's not possible to declare final in this case.

My question is that after initailization of this class how to prevent it from unwanted changes without final declaration.

Thank you !

Comment: make it private and final. Then provide a getter only. You have to make sure that this variable has to be initialized either with declaration or in constructor

Comment: make your class `singleton` and define a getter method only

Comment: I can't help making a getter method for it.......?

Comment: None of the responses solved your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Declaring it as `final`, in case of a reference, means that it cannot be reassigned, but still the internal status can be modified (accordingly to the class interface). However, keep in mind that strings in Java are immutable...

Another approach to do what you want is to declare it as private, then define a `public getter` and **no** `setter`.
This would help if the aim is to initialize it during the bootstrap by reading a configuration values from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the variable final, but you can make it private, so that only this class can read and write it directly.

Then provide a public getter so that other classes can read it but not write its value.

Now it is up to you as implementor of this class not to change its value.

Also, you don't want it to be static, since you will otherwise change the value every time you instantiate this class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it final because you are using @PostConstruct. This means that the class gets instantiated and then, Spring assign some values to it because of the @PostConstruct annotation. As others have said, you have to make it private and just provide a getter, not a setter.